# Ubuntu Installation on Lenovo Ideapad G780

Tags: installation, dual-boot, lenovo

I am not new to Ubuntu however, I'm having trouble installing it on a new Lenovo Ideapad laptop model G780. It came pre-loaded with Windows 8. When I install Ubuntu, it's fine but at dual-boot it gives me the following error:

```
File Missing or Corrupt
/ubuntu/winboot/wubilder.mbr Status 0x000007b
```

I have to boot it from Wubi because the CD/DVD is not listed when I press F12 to go to the boot menu.

Comment: wubi.exe is not working always good , especially on Laptops with Windows 8 (and I presume EFI and Secure Boot ON). Try to do a regular installation of Ubuntu (on a separate partition). But first , [read this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Comment: WUBI does not work with UEFI and Windows 8. It won't be included from the next version of Ubuntu (13.04) to be released in a couple of days. See [Installing Ubuntu on a pre-installed UEFI supported Windows 8 system](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

Answer (score 0):

The disk isn't booting because your computer doesn't recognize 32-bit OS. Burn and boot the 64-bit image for windows 8 with UEFI.